# Getting Values in Userform on searching a reference number

Tags: database, vba, excel, userform

Hi I am looking to return the values from a specific row in a table using a userform. I had some success with a code on updating values and thought by tweaking the code I could get it to do the opposite pulling the values back into the userform. I would be very greatful if someone could assist

```
Private Sub Find_Click()

Dim searchRange As Range
Dim foundCell As Range
Dim mysearch As String

mysearch = Me.Search.Value

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Master Data")
    Set searchRange = .Range("A2", .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
End With

Set foundCell = searchRange.Find(what:=mysearch, Lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
If Not foundCell Is Nothing Then
    Me.MerchInstall.Value = foundCell.Offset(0, 7).Value
    Me.ReOrderCode.Value = foundCell.Offset(0, 13).Value
Else
     MsgBox "ID does not exist."
End If

End Sub
```

Thanks,

Comment: Is the code working? Do you get an error message or does it run without errors. If there is no error message then please elaborate what it does and what it should do. Also, please include some screenshots of the `Master Data` sheet and the form. For the form please also include what `Me.Search`, `Me.MerchInstall`, etc. refers to on the user form. In short, please provide us with a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Sorry I seem to have managed to solve the issue now :)

Comment: @MBrann - if you've been able to solve your own problem, post the solution as an answer - it may help others who have the same problem! :]